# jQuery Multiselect plugin returns null length (should be 0?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, null

Using jQuery Multiselect plugin and need to check if any selections have been made (user may open and close select box without choosing anything).  This plugin has a "close" method which I use to get the array of selected/checked options:

```
var checkedVals = [];
checkedVals = $('#'+which).val();   // Get Array of checked options
alert(checkedVals.length);      // See if it's empty
```

When an option is selected/checked, it works fine (so I know I'm returning values) but when nothing is selected, Firebug throws an error stating that checkedVals is null.  An empty array should be 0... not null.  And pls... let's not get into the discussion of trying to trap "null".

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's perfectly possible for `$('#'+which).val()` to return `undefined`, which would mean `checkedVals` **isn't** an empty array and cause the error you're encountering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it like this and you will always have an array

```
var checkedVals = $('#'+which).val() || [];
alert(checkedVals.length);
```

It will set checkedVals to the .val() value or to an empty array if it's null (falsey).

Answer (score 3):

From the [jQuery documentation on .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the .val() method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns **null**.

So `.val()` is behaving as expected and your code is correct, except that you must add a check for the perfectly reasonable possibility that `.val()` can return null.

Comment: Okay... thanks.  It does actually return "undefined" when I just check the array itself.  That's why I tried the .length method.  I'll try trapping null, "null", or whatever val() is returning.